# save excel file as text without delimiter and keep empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel sheet want to save it as txt file, but without delimiter, and same time to keep space of the empty cell in range

[image]

[image: the desired output]

below is code

```
    Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xFile As Variant
Dim xFileString As String
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Define Range"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ActiveSheet.Copy
Application.ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
WorkRng.Copy Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
Set xFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")



xFileString = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("") 'fileFilter:="Comma Separated Text (*.CSV), *.CSV")
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xFileString & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are worried about "visible" delimiters like "," or ";" then use TAB as a dilimiter. That will maintian the sanctity of the data inclusing the empty cells.

Comment: In my opinion, if those are the requirements, you are going to end up with a mess no matter what you do.

Comment: You only showed the output, but what is the input? Please show a screenshot of the sheet that should produce the output you show.

Comment: You are saving as file as *.CSV which is Comma Separated Variable. Empty cells are delimited by commas and commas separate the numbers or contents of the file.

Comment: @SolarMike actually he is not saving as CSV but as `*.txt` using `FileFormat:=xlText` which is the same as `xlCurrentPlatformText` according to [XlFileFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ but without any placeholders for empty cells what happens, likewritingacommentwithnospacesbetweenthewords.

Comment: @SolarMike Well in my system `FileFormat:=xlText` produces tab seperated values in text format.

Comment: This is a strange request, but if you must do it, I would recommend to save it using a delimiter (let us say, comma) and then read the whole file text/string in a variable and replace/remove the delimiter and put it in the final text file...

Comment: One might save the worksheet with any delimiter, say a comma, and then re-write the text file replacing commas with nothing.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ so tabs can be "placeholders" the point I was making as well as commas etc...

Comment: Thanks for the help, edit it the question with the input file

Comment: So, **do you have a space in the cells looking empty**, or you do you need the code to replace the emptiness with a space in the text file?

Comment: @FaneDuru I have empty cells and I want it to be in the output file, but in the same time I dont want any kind of delimiter (not Tab or ,) the desired output: 1234  4444 444 in other words I need to concatenate the row including the empty space.

Comment: Did you try my code? It does exactly what you say...

Comment: yes, your code separate them with space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It assumes that in the cells looking empty in your picture, there is not any space, they are just empty:

```
Sub testSaveAsTextNoDelim()
   Dim fileSaveName As String, fileNam As String, TempNam As String
   Dim fso As Object, txtStr As Object, Fileout As Object, strText As String

   fileNam = "textWithoutDelim.txt" 'the name you want for the txt file
   fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=fileNam, _
                                 Filefilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

    If fileSaveName <> "" Then
        'create a temporary name for a text file to be processed:
        TempNam = left(fileSaveName, Len(fileSaveName) - 4) & "1.txt"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=TempNam, FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS  'xlTextWindows

        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        Set txtStr = fso.OpenTextFile(TempNam)
            strText = txtStr.ReadAll 'read all the content in a string variable
        txtStr.Close
        strText = Replace(strText, vbTab & vbTab, " ")'replace double Tab with space " "
        strText = Replace(strText, " " & vbTab, "  ") 'replace Tab and " " with double spaces
        strText = Replace(strText, vbTab, "") 'replace all Tabs
        'drop the processed string in the file you need:
        Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(fileSaveName, True, True)
            Fileout.Write strText
        Fileout.Close
        'here you can close the created workbook and Kill the file...
        MsgBox "Saved as " & fileSaveName
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @rayan salah: Glad I could help! But now it would be good to try understanding the code. It is not a big deal...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
Sub SaveAsText()

    '===============================================================
    '       First get the used range
    '===============================================================
    Dim cells As Range
    Set cells = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    '===============================================================
    '       Now, iterate over all cells and store data
    '===============================================================
    'Open a text file to write data in
    Dim myFile As String
    myFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\output.txt"
    
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim str As String
    row = 1 'used to write each Excel row in a single row in the text file
    For Each cell In cells
        
        'Is it a new row?
        If cell.row <> row Then 'yes
            
            'Write the previous row's values
            Write #1, str
            
            'Update row
            row = row + 1
            
            'Reset str
            str = cell.Value
            
        Else 'no
            
            'Update str
            If IsEmpty(cell) Then
                str = str & " "
            Else
                str = str & cell.Value
            End If
            
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    'Write the last str
    Write #1, str
    

    'Close the file
    Close #1
    
End Sub
```

This code generates the following output for your example:
[image]

I have named the output file as "output.txt". You can name it whatever you desire.